# How to get cabal-install Distribution.Client.IndexUtils

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install

I were trying to add `cabal-install` and `Cabal-install` to .cabal file but.

At least the following dependencies are missing: `Cabal-install -any`

Why there is no `cabal-install`?

So how can I get `Distribution.Client.IndexUtils` except of embedding cabal-install sources?

and `Distribution.Client.IndexUtils` too.

Or maybe I can replace it with something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, `cabal-install` is a package that provides an executable, but no library. Therefore, there is no easy way to use functionality provided by `cabal-install` in other tools. A common approach is to write wrapper programs that invoke the `cabal` binary and query it for information.

Having some of the functionality of `cabal-install` available as a library is a valid and reasonable goal, but it might take a while before this happens.

As to the error message: If a package installs only an executable, it is not registered as a library with GHC. Therefore, if you list `cabal-install` as a dependency of another package, you will get the error message that `cabal-install` is missing (as a library).

Comment: I see, so do you suggest to keep cabal embedded in the project? or create hacky wrapper to binary cabal-install...

Comment: I think that really depends on what you intend to do.